# Uglify bundled JS from Browserify

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6, browserify, uglifyjs

I have the following modules installed:

- babelify
- babel-preset-es2015
- browserify
- uglifyify

Now I have a core file `server.js` which contains ES6 javascript. I can convert the ES6 to ES5 and bundle the code for browsers with the following command:

```
browserify server.js -o ./public/bundle.js -t [ babelify --presets [es2015] ]
```

But now I want to get `uglifyify` **minifying the code** and **adding a source map**. I can't get this working, I just can't work out the correct command. I've tried the following:

```
browserify server.js -t uglifyify -t [ babelify --presets [es2015] ] -o ./public/bundle.js

browserify server.js -o ./public/bundle.js -t [ uglifyify, babelify --presets [es2015] ]

browserify server.js uglifyify -o ./public/bundle.js -t [ babelify --presets [es2015] ]
```

and even without babel:

```
browserify server.js -o ./public/bundle.js -t uglifyify
browserify server.js -t uglifyify -o ./public/bundle.js
```

Comment: Just a wild guess but maybe it is how you installed uglifify. For example, for whatever reason, I couldn't install it globally like I did browserify and watchify and make it work (thus, no `-g` with `npm`). If it helps, this is working for me in a script: `NODE_ENV=production browserify -t [ babelify --presets [ es2015 react ] ] -g uglifyify scripts/index.jsx -o bundle.js` I still need something else like uglifyjs for better compression though. Haven't worked that in yet.

Answer (score 3):

It's not enough to have `uglifyify` installed locally - you also need to install [**uglify-es**](https://github.com/mishoo/UglifyJS2/tree/harmony) globaly, since it's used by the `uglifyify`. You install it like so:

```
npm i -g uglify-es
```

Then you use it like so:

```
browserify server.js -o ./public/bundle.js -t uglifyify
```

#### Using it with babelify

If you also need `babelify` here's how to do it:

```
browserify server.js -o ./public/bundle.js -t uglifyify -t babelify
```

#### Using uglify-es directly

You can also skip using `uglifyify` altogether by using `uglify-es` directly like so:

```
browserify server.js | uglifyjs -c > ./public/bundle.js
```

The sole purpose of `uglifyify` is so that `uglify-es` can be used as a `browserify` **transform**.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you need to use the Pipe "|" in order to make multiple procedures
Try this:

```
browserify server.js -t babelify | uglifyjs > public/bundle.js
```

I hope it helps, otherwise i'll be happy to keep helping you with this issue ;)

Best Regards.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Still not working for me though. I tried this: `browserify server.js -t babelify | uglifyify > bundle.js` but I get the error: `uglifyify: command not found`. Should I be using `uglifyjs` instead? Do I need to be using `--plugin`? Looks like that's what `minifyify` does: https://github.com/ben-ng/minifyify

Comment: maybe because you have a typo there "uglifyify" should be "uglifyjs"

Comment: Be sure to install the library as global first by doing 
     npm install -g uglify-js

Comment: If I need to use `uglify-js`, then what's `uglifyify` for? https://www.npmjs.com/package/uglifyify

Comment: I've managed to achieve my goal using minifyify now. Still bugging me why uglifyify won't work though.

Comment: @Coop: `uglifyify` is the browserify transform wrapper around `uglify-js`.